# On scroll up/down trigger a function once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load 2 different animated graphic on window scroll up/down on a website by triggering some functions, it's working but its buggy as the functions are triggered too many times when scrolling:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      headerHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

       if(scroll > headerHeight) {
          loadLogoAnimeDown();
       }else{
          loadLogoAnimeUp();
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to check if the functions have been called (and logo has been loaded), so you can use a variable for that. After the logo has been loaded, you set the variable as false, which prevents them from loading more than once.

```
var downNotLoaded = true;
var upNotLoaded = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
  headerHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

   if(scroll > headerHeight) {
      if(downNotLoaded){
       loadLogoAnimeDown();
       downNotLoaded = false;
      }

   }else{
      if(upNotLoaded){
       loadLogoAnimeUp();
       upNotLoaded = false;
      }
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this is a very hacky way to do it, but this should work.

```
var animated;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
  headerHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

   if(scroll > headerHeight) {
      if (animated == true) {
         loadLogoAnimeDown();
         animated = false;
      }
   } else{
      if (animated == false) {
         loadLogoAnimeUp();
         animated = true;
      }
   }
});
```